# Using "watch" to run a function repeatedly in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, function, command, watch

This is my first Bash script. I have a WiFi issue with my Debian machine. I'm not here to ask about the cause, but rather how to put a band-aid on the issue with Bash. My WiFi will drop out at a random time, usually every 12-15 minutes. I use SSH on this server, and do not want to have to run `ifdown wlan0` and `ifup wlan0` (which reconnects the WiFi) manually from the physical server.

The function of this Bash script is to attempt to connect three times. If it fails three times, it will give up. Otherwise, every three seconds it will check whether or not my server is connected by attempting to ping Google.

```
#!/bin/bash

ATTEMPTS=1

function test_connection {
  ping -c 1 www.google.com
  local EXIT_CODE=$?
  if [ $EXIT_CODE -eq 0 ]
    then
      return true
    else
      return false
  fi
}
function reset_connection {
  ifdown wlan0
  ifup wlan0
  EXIT_CODE=$((EXIT_CODE+1))
}
function connection_test_loop {
  if [ $ATTEMPTS -ge  3 ]
    then
      echo CONNECTION FAILED TO INITIALIZE ... ATTEMPT $ATTEMPTS FAILED ... EXITING
      exit
  fi
  if ! [ test_connection ]
    then
      echo CONNECTION DROPPED ... ATTEMPTING TO RE-ESTABLISH CONNECTION ... ATTEMPT $ATTEMPTS
      reset_connection
  fi
}

test_connection
if [ $? ]
  then
    echo CONNECTION PRE-ESTABLISHED
    watch -n 3 connection_test_loop
  else
    echo CONNECTION FAILED TO INITIALIZE ... ATTEMPTING TO RESET CONNECTION ... ATTEMPT $ATTEMPTS
    reset_connection
    if [ $? ]
      then
        echo CONNECTION ESTABLISHED
        watch -n 3 connection_test_loop
      else
        echo CONNECTION FAILED TO INITIALIZE ... ATTEMPT $ATTEMPTS FAILED ... EXITING
        exit
    fi
fi
```

I've isolated the issue I'm having with this script. It lies in calling the `connection_test_loop` function with `watch`. I've been unable to find any information as to why this isn't performing as expected and running the function every three seconds.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### tldr

00 use `watch -x bash` to watch bash

01 pass your function as a command of :bash ie `bash -c yourcommand`

```
watch -x bash -c  yourcommand

watch -x bash -c 'yourcommand arg0 arg1 ...'
```

---

### in detail

It's possible that `watch` is not aware of your connection_test_loop function. You can try adding an **[`export`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/exporth.html)** below the test_connection to perhaps solve the issue:

```
test_connection
export -f connection_test_loop
...
```

↳ http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/exporth.html

When calling `watch`, you may need this syntax:

```
watch -x bash -c connection_test_loop
```

And if your function has some arguments, make sure you surround the function call and these parameters with quotes, e.g.:

```
watch -x bash -c "connection_test_loop my_arg1 my_arg2"
```

Comment: `export -f function-name` not working for me on ubuntu server 16.04 - you have some idea?

Comment: Only `watch -x bash -c my-func` work for me on Ubuntu Server 16.04 - while others don't.

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple aliases and functions that used to not work with `watch` until I created a function that wraps the `watch` command like this, inspired from @l'L'l accepted answer:

```sh
# fishshell
function watch
    command watch -n 0.2 -x fish -c "$argv"
end

# bash
function watch() {
    watch -n 0.2 -x bash -c "$@"
}

# zsh
watch() {
    watch -n 0.2 -x zsh -c "$@"

}
```

The only inconvenient I see here is that you can't pass more watch arguments if you want to, for sure me I added the `-n 0.2` flag to make it refresh every 0.2 seconds, if you have other flags that you like to add you will need to add them here beforehand.

Personally I only use `fishshell` so I hope the others are not broken, don't hesitate to edit the answer to fix the commands!

Also as a bonus for the lazy that often use watch: `alias w=watch`

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on @I'L'l 's response, I wrote this up to just export all functions to the subshell, and call it a day.  Note, the regex expects a function declared like so: `my_function ()`; of course, you can tailor it to your needs (like, I egrep -v all `nvm` related functions.)

```
watch() {
  for i in $( declare -pf | egrep '^[A-Za-z0-9_]+ \(\)' | awk '{ print $1 }' ) ; do
    export -f $i
  done
  command watch "$@"
}
```