# watch has no access to function defined in .zshrc

Tags: terminal, zsh

I define a function in my `.zshrc` like:

```sh
function foo {
  echo bar
}
```

I can run this function myself:

```sh
$ foo
bar
```

But I can't use `watch` to run it:

```sh
$ watch foo
sh: 1: foo: not found
```

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35006244/2071807) shows how to do it with Bash:

```sh
$ watch -x bash foo
```

But this doesn't seem to work for zsh.

How can I run my user-defined function with `watch`?

Comment: It might also be interesting to know why this doesn't work. What is `watch` doing internally?

Comment: Isn't this relevant and maybe crucial: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59360/what-is-the-zsh-equivalent-of-bashs-export-f

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ watch -x zsh -ic foo
```

- `zsh` - shell.  This is how you get to a zsh function.
- `-i` - interactive.  `~/.zshrc` is only sourced for interactive shells.
- `-c` - indicates that `foo` is a command, not a shell script file to read in.
- `watch -x` - have watch use `exec` instead of `sh -c` ([man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html)). Reduces the number of processes involved a bit.

If using an interactive shell here causes problems, you can move your function to `~/.zshenv`. Then you won't need the `-i` option, since `~/.zshenv` is sourced for both interactive shells and [shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609282/configuration-file-for-shell-script/609699#609699).

Answer (score 0):

Shell functions are internal to the shell, so naturally external programs can't use them. One general way to call shell functions in such situations is using `zsh -c 'ZSH_CODE_HERE'`.

Comment: Is there a formulation to make this work with `watch`?